# Aligning an image or background image to bottom right of twitter bootstrap hero box

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do you align an image or background image to the bottom right of this [fluid hero box example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html) in twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 4):

write like this:

```
div{
 background-position:bottom right;
}
```

Comment: tried `<div style="background-position:bottom right;background-image:url('image.png')"></div>` ... nothing is showing up

Answer (score 3):

You can use the bootstrap `.pull-right` class with some top margin to push an image to the bottom right, or define your background-position to the bottom right as the other posted suggested.

```
<img class="pull-right" style="margin-top:10px;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
```

Comment: @ina If you add the `background-image` to a new class and add it to the container of the hero box you can a background image.

Comment: @ina Here is a of a background image: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/WtwnY/show/ ... [edit here](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/WtwnY/)

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange background image to left bottom by using the following CSS

```
div{
 background-image: url('/Holding.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-position: left bottom;
}
```

For reference you can [check here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position).